How to use hibernate filter with jpa using aop?
i want to create aspect that will cover soft delete functionality. hibernate filter works flawlessly with jpa, here is the sample code.
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BlogPostServiceImpl implements BlogPostService {

    private BlogPostRepository blogPostRepository;
    private BlogPostResponseMapper blogPostResponseMapper;

    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public BlogPostResponse getBlogPostById(UUID id) {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.enableFilter(SOFT_DELETE_FILTER);
        BlogPost blogPost = blogPostRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()->new ResourceNotFoundException("Blog post not found"));
        session.disableFilter(SOFT_DELETE_FILTER);
        return blogPostResponseMapper.modelToDto(blogPost);
    }
}

when i try to use it with aspect, the aspect is running but the filter's condition is not added into the query.
service
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BlogPostServiceImpl implements BlogPostService {

    private BlogPostRepository blogPostRepository;
    private BlogPostResponseMapper blogPostResponseMapper;

    @PersistenceContext
    public EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public BlogPostResponse getBlogPostById(UUID id) {
        BlogPost blogPost = blogPostRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(()->new ResourceNotFoundException("Blog post not found"));
        return blogPostResponseMapper.modelToDto(blogPost);
    }
}

aspect
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(0)
public class SoftDeleteAspect {
    @Before("execution(* com.sample.cms.service..*.*(..))")
    public void beforeExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Class<?> classAspect = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
        Field[] fields = classAspect.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (StringUtils.equals("entityManager", field.getName())) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) field.get(joinPoint.getTarget());
                Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
                session.enableFilter(SOFT_DELETE_FILTER);
            }
        }
    }
    @After("execution(* com.sample.cms.service..*.*(..))")
    public void afterExecution(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Class<?> classAspect = joinPoint.getTarget().getClass();
        Field[] fields = classAspect.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (StringUtils.equals("entityManager", field.getName())) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) field.get(joinPoint.getTarget());
                Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
                session.disableFilter(SOFT_DELETE_FILTER);
            }
        }
    }
}

what should i do to make it work?

You have an execution pointcut but we don't know if the package is correct. I would ditch the reflection to get the EntityManager and just inject the EntityManager into the aspect which will greatly simplify your aspect code. Finally you want to make this an @Around which will make it easier as well. Finally do you really need the filter why not use the @Where annotation to exclude them automatically? See https://thorben-janssen.com/implement-soft-delete-hibernate/ (which gives a nice overview of the options available).

Hi, thanks for your suggestion. Now my code is working, thank you very much. I avoid using Where annotation because, I cannot retrieve deleted data using Where annotation. I really appreciate your help, your answer means a lot to me, I asked several questions about spring, but were always got down vote, including this one. Once again, thanks a lot.
